# Dropping element from list pyspark

Tags: python, list, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a list in pyspark that has the following format:

```
[(u'category1',
  [u'a',
   u'b',
   u'c',
   u'd']),
(u'category2',
  [u'v',
   u's',
   u'g',
   u'd'])]
```

I would like to drop the category elements from this list. Is there any clean way of doing this in pyspark?

Comment: Not familiar with pyspark.  Can you use a list comprehension? `[x[1] for x in my_list]`

Comment: How about this [(x[1],) for x in l] ?

Comment: Do you mean a `rdd`? You can probably just do `rdd.map(lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: yes exactly that I was looking for! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments bellow my question say, this is the answer:

```
[x[1] for x in my_list]
```